# VS 2008 starter kit for building dotnetnuke module

Tags: dotnetnuke

I am looking to build a dotnetnuke module for the latest 5.1 version. I could not find a starter kit or vs 2008 template. Any ideas? links or pointers where I can download it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it...

http://dotnetnuke.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=29122